# How to install pyvmomi

Tags: python, vmware, esxi, vmware-tools

Can I install pyvmomi package on ESXi? If so how? is there any documentation on this?
There is no `pip` available and when I tried to just copy the python files I find out that it depends on .so files on Linux and .dll on Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyVmomi` is already present on ESXi. However it may not be part of its PYTHONPATH. You can find the directory and if you add it to PYTHONPATH then you should be able to use it right away.

Comment: Any idea where it could be found? I looked for pyVmomi and nothing showed up?